# How can I flatten this array format?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to turn the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [535fd7566a10d96c2ac04d2e26e210c4] => Jane Apple
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [3cdacd430d6a70acbe4caf9712a76824] => Johnny Apple
        )
...
)
```

into the following format.

```
    Array
    (
                [535fd7566a10d96c2ac04d2e26e210c4] => Jane Apple,
                [3cdacd430d6a70acbe4caf9712a76824] => Johnny Apple,
...
            )
```

I have tried a few different functions found through the stack-overflow, and google but no luck.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve my desired result?

Thank you,

Comment: I'd just iterate over the old array and create the new one. What specific methods have you tried and why didn't they work?

Comment: what did you code for make this?

Comment: `foreach ($array as $element) foreach ($element as $key => $value) $output[$key]=$value;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe

```
array_reduce($array, 'array_merge', [])
```

should do the trick

essentially you want to reduce an array of values (each an array) to one value (an array) hence array_reduce. and merge takes an item (the array) and merges it with another array (the carry in this case) to produce the array you want.

just wanted to provide a non-loop answer ;o)

Answer (score 3):

Run two `foreach` loops; one nested underneath the other; That way you will get the desired result:

1. The first loop will allow you to run through the original array
2. Second `foreach` will separate the array and "flatten" it.

Shall we get started,

```
// setup array
$array = array (

    0 => array(
            '535fd7566a10d96c2ac04d2e26e210c4' => 'Jane Apple'
        ),

    1 => array(
            '3cdacd430d6a70acbe4caf9712a76824' => 'Johnny Apple'
        )
    );

    // first foreach loop will take original array and loop through it creating a new one
    foreach ($array as $new_array)
    {
        // now loop through the new array and separate it as key value pair; you will now have the desired result
        foreach ($new_array as $key => $val)
        {
             $user[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
```

You will get the following output:

```
Array
(
    [535fd7566a10d96c2ac04d2e26e210c4] => Jane Apple
    [3cdacd430d6a70acbe4caf9712a76824] => Johnny Apple
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a single loop like this:

```
<?php

print_r($arr = [
    ['535fd7566a10d96c2ac04d2e26e210c4' => 'Jane Apple'],
    ['3cdacd430d6a70acbe4caf9712a76824' => 'Johnny Apple']
]);

foreach ($arr as $v) {
    $key = array_keys($v)[0];
    $arr2[$key] = $v[$key];
}

print_r($arr2);

?>
```