# How do I print a multidimensional array that varies with depth in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, implode

I have the following example of array output. I need to find a way to convert this array to a string or output the emails in an organized way. I have tried implode but I only receive an "Array" output. Please help!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Email
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => test1@gmail.com
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => test2@gmail.com
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => test3@gmail.com
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => test4@gmail.com
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => test5@gmail.com
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: What's the expected output, and what have you tried so far.

Comment: Why is there a single Array with only one Element which is another Array with 6 Arrays in it? If you control this, change it.

Comment: @Christy I understand that you are using PHPExcel, is there any chance you could show us a pastebin of the code you are using for extraction? It seems odd that it would create an output such as this.

Comment: @JustCarty It's actually part of a Wordpress plugin I'm building. I would love another set of eyes if you're willing help. My email is sparkswebdev@gmail.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr[0]); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($arr[0][$i]); $j++) {
        echo $arr[0][$i][$j];
    }
}
```

The above will output each string of the array.
The only question I have is why you are storing single strings so deep in an array? Perhaps we could see more of the code?

The below code would be simpler for what you provided:

```
$arr[] = "Email";
$arr[] = "test1@gmail.com";
$arr[] = "test2@gmail.com";
$arr[] = "test3@gmail.com";
$arr[] = "test4@gmail.com";
$arr[] = "test5@gmail.com";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    echo $arr[$i];
}
```

Even better, use array keys instead:

```
$arr["Email"][] = "test1@gmail.com";
$arr["Email"][] = "test2@gmail.com";
$arr["Email"][] = "test3@gmail.com";
$arr["Email"][] = "test4@gmail.com";
$arr["Email"][] = "test5@gmail.com";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr["Email"]); $i++) {
    echo $arr["Email"][$i];
}
```

Comment: You are awesome! This worked. I'm using phpexcel to read a column from an imported excel doc. with this code: $lead_email_array[] = $excelObj->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->rangeToArray($selected_lead_email);

Comment: @Christy Ah, that would explain the rogue "Email" at the start of the array. I'm pleased you found a working solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the array a level and then create a `foreach` loop which will allow for you to get them organized and print each unique item as you want.

The `array_reduce` will save you from having to create a second loop, and make things easier for you, also takes less computing power. I got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46136572/1527252).

```
<?php
// reduce array
array_reduce($array, 'array_merge', []);
// create the loop
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
{
    // this will print the emails in a list format
    echo '<li>' . $v . '</li>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if the some arrays go deeper than others is to use a recursive print function. This way it will iterate through every value, and if the value is an array it repeats the process with that new array util it finds something to print that is not an array.

```
$data = array(array(array("Email"),array("some@email.com"),array("another@email.com")),array("outisde@gmail.com"));

function recursivePrint($array) {
    foreach($array as $value) {
        if (gettype($value) === 'array') {
            recursivePrint($value);
        } else {
            print($value . ", ");
        }
    }
}

recursivePrint($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the only array you need to use? Will there be any other arrays like this in the future? Implode only works for sibling items in the same array, so you need something like:

```
<?php

$array = array(
  "test1@gmail.com",
  "test2@gmail.com",
  "test3@gmail.com",
  "test4@gmail.com",
  "test5@gmail.com"
);

$result = implode( ',', $array );

echo $result;
// test1@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com,test3@gmail.com,test4@gmail.com,test5@gmail.com
```